# Unnecessary use of "your" in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, error

> You should always check your oil, water and tyres before taking your
>   car on a long trip.

In the example above, "your" has been used twice. Is the first "your" necessary?

<sub>Source: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trip?q=Trip</sub>

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using *your* twice. No rule of grammar says that sentences must always be reduced to the smallest possible number of words needed to convey the intended meaning. In some languages it might be preferable to use *the* rather than *your* there, but English isn't one of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Your" is a possessive adjective. The first instance of "your" in the sentence shows ownership of the elements of the car: oil, water, and tyres. The second instance of "your" shows ownership of the car itself. It is grammatically correct. However, replacing the first instance of "your" with "the" is also acceptable and grammatically correct.

Comment: To note, it would sound a *little* off if you replaced the second "your" with "the", as it breaks the parallelism. As if I might check my car's oil (a Ford, say), water, and tyres before taking "the" car (my car? Some other car in front of me? Etc) on a trip?

Comment: @BruceWayne: or as if they're suggesting you check *your* oil, water and tyres, *not* the car's. Presumably you are some kind of wheeled robot ;-)

Comment: Colloquially, if the car was family property and the parent was talking to the child, then your/the would be normal.  As in a father talking to his son "You'll want to make sure you check your oil, water, and tires before taking the car on a long trip."

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I would argue **no**, this is not grammatically correct, as the first "your" should refer to *the car's* "oil, water and tyres"</strike> (see comments). As the sentence originally is written, it implies that the *owner of the car* requires a pre-trip oil checkup (which is silly, unless you are a robot).

In my opinion, the more correct version of this sentence is:

> You should always check your car's oil, water, and tyres before taking it on a long trip.

It's not *your* oil, water, or types that you're checking; it's your car's. Therefore, the possessive belongs to the car itself, not to you. Furthermore, you can remove the second "your" in the sentence by referring to the car as "it".

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: I like the way you re-worded the sentence but I disagree that the original sentence is grammatically incorrect. What if the OP is a robot and they really wanted to check their oil, water and tires? You wouldn't say it is not grammatically correct. At most it is ambiguous. But that ambiguity goes away because of context. Of course he is not a robot.

Comment: I like Dan's argument, but agree with Andrew that context tells us we're referring to the car's oil/water/tyres. A native speaker would not question that, nor would it sound incorrect or odd. It would be like if my car won't start and someone asked, "Did you check your battery?"

Comment: You're both right, in that the context here guides the reader/listener to the correct interpretation. However, I stand firm that it's not grammatically correct. As native speakers, we say things that are grammatically incorrect all the time, yet this generally does not impair comprehension. The sentence, judged strictly on grammar, means something different than what is intended.

Comment: Well, no, it doesn't though does it? Firstly you're confusing grammar, this being the organising principles of the language, the means by which we put sentences together, with meaning. "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" is a famous example of a sentence which is grammatically correct, but nonsensical. But in any case, it is your oil, isn't it, since you paid for it. If it's your car, they're your wheels, your seats, your steering wheel, your engine and your spark plugs, so that kind of pedantry doesn't really get you anywhere.

Comment: But in any case, that's actually not the point, since we use 'your' all the time to mean something relating to you, or something you're in charge of. For example, "start your engines!" This is what racing car drivers get told, even though they probably don't own their cars or their engines. Nobody announces "start your cars' engines!" because this is a perfectly legitimate use of 'your' and insisting it's technically incorrect is just technically incorrect

Comment: @Au101 Good points all around. You've managed to convince me. :)

Comment: I am the owner of the  oil in my car.  I am the owner of the tyres on my car.  If I check them, then I am checking _my_ oil and _my_ tyres.  So the use of _your_ here is perfectly correct.

Comment: @DavidWallace While you are the owner of the oil and the tyres, it sounds incorrect. Imagine saying "make sure your battery is full before you take your laptop to the coffee shop." You are the owner of your laptop's battery, but that sounds very odd, no?

Comment: @DanLoewenherz The original sentence does not sound at all incorrect to me, and I am a university-educated native speaker.  Moreover, the original source was a reputable British English dictionary; and the fact that the compilers of the dictionary saw fit to include it as an example indicates that it didn't sound incorrect to them either.  Perhaps it sounds incorrect to speakers of some English dialects but not others.  I think the reason why your example with the laptop battery sounds a bit odd is that most people own several batteries, but only own the oil in one car.

Comment: @DavidWallace University-educated native speaker here as well. Different strokes for different folks. IMO it sounds odd. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯